# How to avoid calling a too much parameterized constructor, with virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, constructor, virtual-inheritance, method-signature

I want to perform a virtual inheritance with the following obvious example :

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {}
private:
    int m_a;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), m_b(b) {}
private:
    int m_b;
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    C(int a, int c) : A(a), m_c(c) {}
private:
    int m_c;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int a, int b, int c) : A(a), B(a, b), C(a, c) {}
};
```

But i don't want to call B(a, b) and C(a, c) because the parameter a is useless in B and C constructors for this particular case of virtual inheritance.

I've found the following article where Jack Reeves proposes some alternatives in order to call default constructors.

http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multiple-inheritance-considered-useful/184402074?pgno=2

Quote :

If we have to completely initialize A before B and C can be constructed, then we have to do initialization with the constructor and we are back to what I showed at first. Alternatively, perhaps you can get by with something like the following:

```
class B : public virtual A {  // class C is similar
public:
    B(int x) : A(x) {}
protected:
    B() : A(0) {}
};
class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D(int x) : A(x) {}  // B and C are default constructed
};
```

End of quote.

So, i kept this idea of protected constructor but i don't want to use the default constructor. I've implemented a singular parameter constructor in A (never called in practice) which use a forward constructor to the "simpliest" valid constructor inside the class (keep the encapsulation of what B and C should call inside A). The single parameter is here to give a unique signature to this "bastard" constructor.

```
// new way
namespace VIRTUAL_INHERITANCE {
struct NEVER_CALLED {};
}

class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {}
protected:
    A(VIRTUAL_INHERITANCE::NEVER_CALLED vinc) : A(0) {}
private:
    int m_a;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), m_b(b) {}
protected:
    B(int b) : A(VIRTUAL_INHERITANCE::NEVER_CALLED()), m_b(b) {}
private:
    int m_b;
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    C(int a, int c) : A(a), m_c(c) {}
protected:
    C(int c) : A(VIRTUAL_INHERITANCE::NEVER_CALLED()), m_c(c) {}
private:
    int m_c;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int a, int b, int c) : A(a), B(b), C(c) {}
};
```

My questions are :

- How to avoid calling a too much parameterized constructor, with virtual inheritance ?
- Is it possible to improve the "unique signature" technique doing something else (with enum for example) ?
- Is anyone has a better technique to do the same thing without having to define a second constructor in A ?
- What are the drawbacks ?

Comment: I quote :

The obvious does not compile:

class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D(int x) : B(x), C(x) {}
};
This generates an error complaining about the lack of a default constructor for A. To make this work we have to write:

D(int x) : A(x), B(x), C(x) {}
While this does work, it is kind of silly because the invocation of the initializer for A is ignored in the B and C constructors when invoked for a D object.

Comment: What programming problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Did you read the entire post ? My questions are at the end.

Comment: *"but i don't want to use the default constructor."* Why?

Comment: @dyp : Good question ! The solution I found ensure the use of the initialize list in a real constructor, instead of a default constructor, which is a conception pervertion, to my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answers are:

- Using default constructor,
- Yes, it is possible with `enum`,
- No. If you want the compiler to **force on you to explicitly call** the constructor of `A`, then you have to declare **additional constructor**. But if you don't... use a default constructor together with an `init` function **or** just a regular, parametrized constructor,
- Drawbacks of having "unique signature" constructor:

  - more code in class `A`,
  - more code in class `B`,
  - more code in class `C`,
  - more code due to dummy structure.
- Drawbacks of having default c-tor with "init" function:

  - you must remember to call `init` function **or** parametrized constructor

Sample (uncluttered) code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {}
protected:
    A() = default;
    void initA(int a) { m_a = a; } // optional
private:
    int m_a;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), m_b(b) {}
protected:
    B(int b) : m_b(b) {}
private:
    int m_b;
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    C(int a, int c) : A(a), m_c(c) {}
protected:
    C(int c) : m_c(c) {}
private:
    int m_c;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int a, int b, int c) : A(a), B(b), C(c) {}
    // or optionally:
    D(int a, int b, int c) : B(b), C(c) { initA(a); }
};
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need that `initA` function. Why don't you just call `D(int a, int b, int c) : A(a), B(b), C(c) {}`?

Comment: Actually, that's the same :) because one need to call it explicitly.

Comment: Not quite. In real life scenarios, `B` &  `C` often rely on `a` being set correctly. Deferring the initalizion is not a good strategy...

Comment: Real life scenarios may be very complex, I agree. However in this context we're discussing the need of specialized constructor. So far it looks like having "unique signature" constructor (as proposed by @cevik) has its benefits, because compiler would scream at you if you forget to call `A`'s constructor while initializing `D`.